# SQLite DB file is converted to text file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

```
SQLite format 3   @                                                                        
   � ��                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             �2�3tablequestionsquestionsCREATE TABLE questions (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question TEXT, answer TEXT, incorrect1 TEXT, incorrect2 TEXT, incorrect3 TEXT, difficulty INTEGER)l--�tableandroid_metadataandroid_metadataCREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
   � �                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             en_US� �    �����������������������                                                                   �
     �%+'What is the name of the virus that Chuck uses series one to defuse a bombIrene DemovaPamela AndersonLindsay LohanLa Ciudad-     ;Who does Casey work forNSAMI5MI6GCHQ- ;Who does Sarah work forCIAMI5MI6GCHQG G!What store does Chuck work atBuy MoreBest BuyWalmartLarge MartW s%What computer game does bryce hide the intersect inZorgCall of DutyZeldaTetrisW s%What computer game does bryce hide the intersect inZorgCall of DutyZeldaTetris�
 Ka==How does Chuck first meet SarahShe comes to Buy More with a broken mobileShe spills coffee on himshe crashes into his carat a bar[ I)+/How does Chuck first meet jilleconomic classplaying pinballonlinewatching footballh 7M%++what is the intersectsecret government super compu� �D� �<� �=   �-   �&   �   �� �� ��    �;   �   p   a   W   O   C   8   0   
(   W   8   
    �  �
f�Q�$�� }             �
```

I have imported a project into Android Studio from GitHub and in the `/assets` folder, I have my DB file. It's a database of questions. When I clicked on it, I was given options and I selected "open as text" and when opened, it displays a mess of all the questions and cannot work with the file like that. I think I have opened it as wrong format and do not know how to change it, I have tried deleting the file and paste in the file again but every time I do, Android Studio shows it as text!

Can someone help me with this and also should I be opening it as a SQL to edit it? If so how?

Comment: android studio wont change your file. what you are seeing is whats in the file. it might not be structured properly or maybe word wrap is enabled. try disabling word wrap.

Comment: originally there was a ? mark as the file and i was given a list of options, i and i selected text and not sql or xml or any of the others so think i selected wrong one

Comment: i have editied and added the displayed code and simply cannot change it while in this format

Comment: you can try opening the original file in notepad++, if it too shows the file like that, that means the file itself is not structured properly.
P.S just pull a new file from the repo.

Comment: hmmmm... seems like an encoding issue. is the repo public? i can take a look at that file for you.

Comment: yea its from github, was using it a learning curve for a project, here a link...https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidChuckQuiz/tree/master/assets

Comment: i think the file will be fine and its just that i chose the wrong option in android studio, just cant seem to revert back to it being a ? file again so i can chose different option

Comment: ahh, so i am not going to be able to edit the questions then?

Comment: ive managed to solve it, i used sql database editor and got the file working in that and using it to edit things, i will accept yours as the answer because you the only one thats helped so thank you very much

Comment: SQLite is not a plain text file, so you can't open it to modify it. As already mention on your comment, you need other application to SQLite view/edit it.